# I don't want to be associated with my question. How can I hide it?

Tags: support, licensing, ownership

One of my highest voted questions on stack exchange, while interesting, is not something I want to be associated with when someone decides to look at my profile. I'd be happier if I had more questions voted above it (quite a few more), or if it simply didn't appear in my list.

Can I make it not appear in my list? Can I decouple myself from the question, or otherwise make my involvement invisible? Specifically for anyone looking at my profile on careers (which hasn't really been developed, precisely *because* I'm not keen on them seeing this question), but, if not, then generally?

Comment: @JoshC actually, you can request to be disassociated from any post, and Stack Exchange is bound by the cc wiki license to honor that request.

Comment: I'm not too worried about it's existence; I don't think it's a bad question. At the time, when I wasn't interested in job-hunting, I had no problems with being associated with it. It's just the context of the careers side of SE that makes me uncomfortable about it (or, more accurately, worried about whether it'd make _others_ uncomfortable).

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir - The question will continue to exist, your account will simply no longer be associated with it. I believe the "Anon" "account" will take it over.